# KVM virtual IP address not working on HOST, works on GUEST

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-12.04

I have a setup composed of the following:

-> A HOST running KVM with the following network configs:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# The bridge used by GUESTS
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 9
  bridge_hello 2
  bridge_maxage 12
  bridge_maxwait 0

  # Configure the bridge to act also as a maintenance interface
  address AAA.BBB.CCC.62
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway AAA.BBB.CCC.1
  dns-nameservers AAA.BBB.CCC.1

# For HOST-GUEST Communications
auto maintenancebr0
iface maintenancebr0 inet static
  gateway FFF.XXX.XXX.2
  dns-nameservers FFF.XXX.XXX.2
  address FFF.XXX.XXX.1
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  # Add this as a gateway with a lower metric so that is used for fallback only
  post-up route add default gw FFF.XXX.XXX.2 metric 2
  pre-down route del default gw FFF.XXX.XXX.2

# The interface giving me troubles, can't access this IP through a direct cable connection
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
   address FFF.XXX.XXX.188
   netmask 255.255.255.240
```

-> A guest running with the following network configs:

```
# Loopback interface:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Ethernet 0 interface:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address AAA.BBB.CCC.67
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway AAA.BBB.CCC.1
   dns-nameservers AAA.BBB.CCC.1

# For HOST-GUEST communication (fallback) connected to maintenancebr0 using libvirt
auto eth7
iface eth7 inet static
address FFF.XXX.XXX.2
netmask 255.255.255.128

# Guest also has a maintenance IP address (this one works fine with a direct cable connection)
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
   address FFF.XXX.XXX.178
   netmask 255.255.255.240
```

My question/issue here is the following, all the rest works just fine: Connecting a cable directly to the HOST machine on the eth0 port and configuring my computer to have the IP address FFF.XXX.XXX.177 allows me to reach the GUEST on FFF.XXX.XXX.178 just fine, however I cannot seem to access the HOST on FFF.XXX.XXX.188, why?

Comment: All this censoring of IP addresses makes it very hard to tell if you could've made a simple mistake typing or copying them.

Comment: Why are you using the old-style `eth0:0` device alias format?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no special reason really, just force of habit, doe it influence anything?

Comment: @gparent i know... bit ridiculous but kind of has to be, i have replaced it by letters, each XXX is equal to eachother, each AAA is equal to each other etc... hope it makes it a bit clearer

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be.